# fabricjs changing viewport breaks coordinates for touch

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

Just like in the title. I have a canvas with a picture in it. Users can zoom using pinch. Everything is fine but as soon as I set viewport width or initial scale, coordinates are going crazy and image jumps back and forth.

I dont know if its fabric related or canvas in general. But maybe some of you already had similar issue?

Here is my code:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editor', { });
const fbImg = new fabric.Image(img, { });
canvas.add(fbImg);
```

It works on mobiles until I put this in

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Please, send help.

**EDIT**

I believe it might have something to do with window.devicePixelRatio which viewport tag changes. I tried disabling retina scaling but it did not help at all.

Comment: if viewport changes window.devicePixelRatio, try to reassign window.devicePixelRatio to fabric.devicePixelRatio or try to initialize your canvas without pixelRatio support.

Answer (score 0):

If you think pixelRatio is the problem, try to work without:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editor', { enableRetinaScaling: false });
```

Comment: Hey, thx for reply. I tried that but the problem remains. As soon as I put two fingers on the picture it gets enlarged or shrinked.